# Is there a way to dynamically change the knob of a seekbar?

Tags: android

I have to implement something like this:

[image]

The face should change position and drawable when i slide it. Very left: happy face. Very right: painful face. I am having 6 drawables for that.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: this is an android question.

Comment: Oooo, duuude, Im soooo sorry. Thats a good lesson not to enter stackoverflow at such a late hours :)

Comment: I implemented a `SeekBar` derivative with an attachable indicator a while ago as the base class for a somewhat similar widget (used as a color picker) - you can check it out in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/corsair992/a0c39530ac32da9b50f4 "AttachableSeekBar"). The drawable set can be wrapped in a [`level-list`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList) resource, and provided as the indicator.

Answer (score 2):

Set a listener for changes in the `SeekBar`, and use `setThumb` to change the drawable.

For example:

```
Drawable thumbA = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb_a);
Drawable thumbB = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb_b);

SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.my_seekbar);
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        // Your logic to change the thumb drawable here
        if (progress < 42) {
            seekBar.setThumb(thumbA);
        } else {
            seekBar.setThumb(thumbB);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
});
```

---

**Additional:**

In it's basic form, the SeekBar widget is built of three image layers.

***1) Background***

This drawable fills the background, and is commonly used to represent the "slot" of a physical slider.
As an example, the default drawable used for the Holo Light theme is:

[image: SeekBar Background] ... progress_bg_holo_light.9.png

Note that this is a 9Patch, and will be stretched to fill the background of the widget in accordance with the guides in the 1 pixel border.

***2) Progress***

This drawable is positioned on top of the Background, and it's size is modified by the widget to indicate the current progress state.
For the Holo Light theme, the default drawable is:

[image: SeekBar Progress] ... progress_primary_holo_light.9.png

Note that this is also a 9Patch. For a horizontal SeekBar this will be stretched vertically to fill the height of the widget, and horizontally to the length representing the current progress.

***3) Thumb***

This drawable is positioned at the end of the Progress drawable, and is commonly used to represent the "knob" of a physical slider.
The default image used for the thumb in the un-pressed state is:

[image: SeekBar Thumb] ... seek_thumb_normal.png

Note that this is *Not* a 9Patch. For a horizontal SeekBar this will be centered vertically within the height of the widget, and placed horizontally at the position representing the current progress.

**Providing Custom Drawables**

You can set the background drawable with `mySeekBar.setBackground(Drawable drawable)`

You can set the progress drawable with `mySeekBar.setProgressDrawable(Drawable drawable)`

When you supply your own custom drawables, it is up to you to ensure the images are defined so that they all line up correctly as you intend.
For example, if you need the "slot" and progress indicator to be positioned lower in the overall height of the widget (which is what you need in your case) then you will need to add **non-stretchable** space above them in their 9Patch images. For example:

[image: SeekBar Background Offset] ... progress_bg_holo_light_offset.9.png

Comment: This kind of works: Face changes, but I am not able to position the face ABOVE the knob. its always on top of the knob.

Comment: Check the **Additional** in my answer.

Comment: The thumb will also need to be changed to be the same height as the  progress `Drawable`, and containing both the original thumb and the indicator `Drawable`s (possibly using a custom `Drawable` wrapper). Another hack would be to define _another_ `SeekBar` with a null progress `Drawable` and the indicators as the thumb positioned at the top of the original `SeekBar`, and set up change listeners on both of them that change the other's progress value. Or you can use my [custom widget](https://gist.github.com/corsair992/a0c39530ac32da9b50f4 "AttachableSeekBar") that was designed for this purpose.

Comment: Note that you can use a [`LevelListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList) container for the indicator set, which will automatically take care of displaying the proper one at the appropriate position. The `maxLevel` attributes should be defined as percentages of a maximum value of 10000.